# Accessibility of combobox UI widget

Tags: accessibility, html, web

I believed ALT+DownArrow is a standard shortcut key to launch the list of options in a `combobox` field. `JAWS` however reads `To set a value use the arrow keys or type a value` when the combobox field gets focus. So should my widget be updated to display dropdown on pressing down arrow key?

Comment: Not a direct answer but WAI-ARIA provides specific guidance for custom combobox widgets (http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#combobox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdowns in html forms expand by default when they get focused and the down arrow key is pressed.
So yes, I would recommend implementing this in your widget as many users certainly have taken this habit whereas only few of them might be comfortable with combined keys shortcuts like ALT+DownArrow.